# Computer isn't saving session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, user-data

The session on a computer is not being saved across pages. It is on my computer, but not on a different one. The computer has cookies enabled. Is there anything that might cause a computer not to save sessions?

Comment: Do they have cookies enabled?

Comment: Is the laptop's system time correct?

Comment: Can you provide more samples?

Comment: Colin, not a duplicate. I originally asked that vague question and had no idea what was going on. Now i narrowed it down and forgot to just edit that one.

Comment: @DylanButh - Can you include the code you're using to set the session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure he has cookies enabled.

This explains why you need cookies enabled for sessions to work:

> The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie {...}
>   The reason to use session tokens is that the client only has to handle the identifier—all session data is stored on the server

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#HTTP_session_token

Comment: Try it in a different web browser. Use Chrome/Firefox/IE (well.. maybe not IE :P ) and see if you get the problem in all three, or just some of the browsers.

Comment: Have a look in the event log and see if anything looks out of place... Use Chrome, take a look in the developer tools -> resources, look under Cookies and Session Storage and see if anything is in either of them.

Comment: Nothing is in either of them. Even when i login successfully from my computer. Both of ours are blank.

Comment: Have you tried it on a third computer? Maybe its being cached for you?

Comment: Yes i have. I tried it on two computers that have never connected before.

Comment: @DylanButh were you able to find a solution to this? I have the same exact problem.

Comment: No i wasnt. Sorry man. Just ended up using a different computer. I'd be very interested if you happen to find one though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') {
      redirect('/auth/');
 }
```

This code is missing a `)` which means it wouldn't parse in PHP. Did you copy and paste from your code?

Comment: I will try it but why would it work for me and not him?

Comment: My apoligies, that is what i have. I was just using the "=" to explain it in the question. I will edit that now.

Comment: It's not possible for `$session->userdata('admin_logged_in') = true` to set any session variables.

Comment: The more code samples you can provide the better.

Comment: I didnt copy and paste. My mistake on that. It has no problem redirecting.